# Assembly (AT&T format) operand value

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm reading this book and I can't find an answer to the following question. Assume the following values are stored at the indicated memory addresses and registers:

0x100 = 0xFF; 0x104 = 0xAB; 0x108 = 0x13; 0x10C = 0x11; %eax = 0x100; %ecx = 0x1; %edx = 0x3.

What (and why) is the value of the following operand?
260(%ecx,%edx)

The operand form is Imm(Eb,Ei) and the operand value should be 
M[Imm + R[Eb] + R[Ei]]. In this case the answer would be M[260 + 0x1 + 0x3] -> M[260+0x4] -> M[264]. However there is no 0x264 address in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 0x... is 0x..., i.e. a [hexadecimal integer](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html#Integers). Without 0x... it is a [decimal integer](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html#Integers). You have to convert "260" from decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: So, the answer would be M[0x104 + 0x4] -> M[0x108] -> 0x13. Great! Thank you.